# Changing the text of an android button also changes its size

Tags: android

I have two android buttons for which I fixed their size in XML with the following code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_width="120dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/player_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/player_name"
    android:onClick="startResetButtonOnClick"
    android:text="@string/start_button_label" />
```

Everything is good when I first create the activity but as soon as I change the text of the button it gets resized. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give fix height and width to button

Comment: @HarshitRathi how can I do that?

Comment: There are also minWidth and maxWidth properties

Comment: try this : 
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="25dp"

Comment: @mariosangiorgio check out my answer, it might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that my issue was caused by the layout I used.
I am using a `RelativeLayout` and I was placing buttons with respect to the borders of a text field that contained changing text and thus was resizing itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `android:textSize="25sp"` to that. At least the text remains at the same size. 
Hope it works

Comment: For text size in android you should use sp instead of dp

Answer (score 1):

You are **setting the size of the button's height to wrap_content**.

This makes the buttons size fit it's text.

**Change wrap_content to a certain amount of pixels** to get the button to stay a certain size.